# Process "kpatch-build" exited unsuccessfully

Tags: c, linux-kernel

When I used the Syscare tool of the openEuler system to create a kernel hot patch, the process failed and the build.log told me:

> Error: KernelPatchBuilder: Failed to build patch
> Caused by:
> Process "kpatch build" exited unsuccessfully, exit_ Code=1

What is the problem?
I tried using the Syscare tool to create a hot patch rpm package using a patch generated by a git diff, but it failed. I hope to eventually generate an rpm package.

Comment: Exit code 1 just means "didn't work". Perhaps there are some other messages before that?

Comment: @BoP: messages before that just is:  
```Process "kpatch-build" (1736466) started```
```Process "kpatch-build" (1736466) exited, exit_code=1```

Comment: Then we just know that the build failed, and we are given no reason. :-(

Comment: @BoP: Finally, the problem was solved. Maybe the function I modified before could not be tracked by the ftrace tracepoint of the kernel, so the kpatch could not be processed. Finally, the compilation failed.  I think the function not in file ```/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/available_events``` cannot use kpatch for kernel hot patch operations